# spring + Embedded jetty + <web-app> - как создать контекст

Tags: java, spring, jetty

есть мавен-проект, с файлом /WEB-INF/web.xml следующего содержания:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>baseWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>baseWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="...."/>
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
         p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
         p:suffix=".jsp"/>
 </beans>
```

Контроллер реализован на основе аннотаций.

Будучи запускаемо посредством  **mvn -Djetty.port=9999 jetty:run** приложение замечательно выполняется. Решил сделать инициализацию jetty в коде, и не могу вручную создать контекст для jetty. Ниже основной класс:

```
public class AppMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler();

/* инициализация контекста .... */

    Server jetty = new Server(9999);
    jetty.setHandler(sch);
    jetty.start();
}
}
```

вопрос: как инициализировать контекст на основе web.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно создать `WebAppContext`.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class AppMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        Server jetty = new Server(9999);

        // Создаем корневой контекст из директории
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext("D:\\some\\path\\to\\webapp\\root", "/"););

        // WebAppContext является ContextHandler, назначаем его серверу 
        jetty.setHandler(webapp);

        // Стартуем и не выключаемся до завершения работы Jetty
        jetty.start();
        jetty.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: пример из учебника не подходит))
потому что war файл - не предполагается

Comment: @dmitrijk, вы хотите стартануть незапакованное веб-приложение?

Comment: да _________________

Comment: @dmitrijk, обновил ответ.